# Reapportioning values using C# and LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, math

I am looking for some assistance with a logic issue and hoped somebody might be able to assist me with an efficient way to solve my problem using **C# and LINQ**.

I have the following list of services with varying terms:

```
Item      | RecurringMonthlyCharge  | Term | Commission
-------------------------------------------------------
Service 1 | $10.00                  | 12   | $100.00
Service 2 | $12.00                  | 18   | $200.00
Service 3 | $14.00                  | 12   | $300.00
```

My aim is to reapportion the `RecurringMonthlyCharge` field evenly (taking into account 'term') after reducing the total commission by $x.

For example, if I discount the **total commission** by $50.00, I'd like to split the $50 over the 3 lines and take into account the term.

Using 'Service 1' as an example, this would work out as:

```
10 - (50/12) = $5.83/mo
```

My question is how to do this over all lines proportionately while taking into account the varying term lengths. Perhaps via a common factor or weighting technique?

**A few points:**

- The commission is for the term (i.e. Service 1 has $100.00 commission
  paid based on a 12 month agreement)
- The total discount applied must
  be deducted evenly from the monthly recurring charges, taking into
  account the term, totalling the final discount amount ($50 in my
  example).

**Attempt #1:**

```
 private static decimal GetRecurringCostEquiv(List<QuotationItemViewModel> items)
        {

            var discVal = GetDiscounts(items, 2);
            decimal? result = 0.00M;

            decimal factor = 1.00M / items.Where(x => x.ProductTypeId == 2).Sum(i => i.RecurringTerm ?? 0);
            result = items.Select(i => i.RecurringCostCore - i.RecurringTerm * factor * discVal).Sum();

            return result ?? 0.00M;
        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be 10 - (50 * (12/(12+18+12))) in this case?

Comment: Could you expand on "**total** commission" and the splitting over the lines? In your example, it seems to be that all $50 of commission reduction has been applied to Service 1?

Comment: @AakashM - In my example, it applies to a single line.  My requirement is to reduce the RecurringMonthlyCharge for each line based on the total discount.

Comment: I added a few points for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example wouldn't you just?

```
var listOfResults = 
  Items.Select(i => i.RecurringMonthlyCharge - (Discount / i.Term))
```

Now, if you **actually** want to reduce this in proportion, the simplest thing is to use the sum of all Terms as a basis for your factor:

```
double factor = 1.0 / Items.Sum(i => i.Term); 
var listOfResults = 
  Items.Select(i => i.RecurringMonthlyCharge - i.Term * factor * Discount))
```

If your data set is huge, some other approach may have to be used, but for reasonable sizes this should work well

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. How can I apply the discount in your second example? It's definitely closer to where I want to be.

Comment: Well, the result of the select is your new RecurringMonthlyCharge, right? So, replace the old value with the new. That can be done in a foreach-loop.

Comment: Thanks for being patient with me, however I'm still not fully getting it. My only input is "total discount", which doesn't appear to be used in the second example you give above.

Comment: Thanks again for the comment. I updated my answer with my method but it's calculating figures that are way off. Any ideas?

Comment: I am confused that you do a sum and only have one result for all items. I thought this is a change for each item? If that's not the case I am afraid I still dont get your requirements...

Comment: The one result for all items is the new 'total' recurring cost (after proportional discounts have been applied). I will be using the individual breakdowns too.

Comment: Way off compared to what? Maybe you should update what values you expect for exactly the three items of your example.

Answer (score 0):

Simple pseudo-code:
`RecurringMonthlyCharge[i] = $50 * RecurringMonthlyCharge[i] / SUM(RecurringMonthlyCharge)`

Specifically you end up with $13.88, $16.66, $19.44. Is that what you're thinking about?

Comment: Thanks for the response but this splits it evenly among the lines. I want to take into account the term (so #2 would be $9.22 (12 - (50/18)). Also, if the commission is reduced, the montly recurring charge is reduced.

Answer (score 0):

If I got requirement correctly next should work:

```
            const double discout = 50;
            var items = new List<Service>()
            {
            new Service{Item = "Service1", RecurringMonthlyCharge = 10, Term = 12, Commision = 100},

            new Service{Item = "Service2", RecurringMonthlyCharge = 12, Term = 18, Commision = 200},

            new Service{Item = "Service3", RecurringMonthlyCharge = 14, Term = 12, Commision = 300}
                            };
            //calculate total terms
            double totalTerms = items.Sum(x => x.Term);
            var searchedItems = items.Select(service => service.RecurringMonthlyCharge - (discout/totalTerms)*service.Term);
```